# CakePHP HABTM w/ FindAll using Containable

Tags: cakephp, conditional-statements, has-and-belongs-to-many

My containable is working, but I need to add a condition from a HABTM relationship.

Company has a HABTM relation with State (companies_states table).

In the below method, I need to check if state_id = 1 (see my commented condition). I am not sure how to include companies_states in my Containable so I can qualify the results.

```
function company_list() {
   return $this->PlanDetail->find('all', array(
      'fields'  => array('id', 'company_id'), 
      'contain' => array('Company' => array(
         'fields' => array('id', 'name',     'short_name')), 
         'State' => array(
            'fields' => array('id')
         )
      ),
      //'conditions' => array('state_id' => 1),
      'group'   => 'Company.name',
      'order'   => array('Company.name ASC')
   ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should have to do anything special... Just add Company in front of state_id

```
function company_list() {
   return $this->PlanDetail->find('all', array(
      'fields'  => array('id', 'company_id'), 
      'contain' => array('Company' => array(
         'fields' => array('id', 'name',     'short_name')), 
         'State' => array(
            'fields' => array('id')
         )
      ),
      'conditions' => array('Company.state_id' => 1),
      'group'   => 'Company.name',
      'order'   => array('Company.name ASC')
   ));
}
```

Comment: But you're not pulling the state_id field anywhere in your fields comments, shouldn't you be doing that?